# Прилагательное "идеалистический" качественное?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные

В одной книге сказано, что *идеалистический* -- это относительое прилагательное. Но ему присуще следующие свойства качественных прилагательных: 1) можно образовывать степени сравнения (его воззрения стали *более* *идеалистическими*), 2) есть краткая форма (его воззрения стали более *идеалистичны*), 3) есть антонимичная пара (идеалистический -- реалистический).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ИДЕАЛИСТИЧЕСКИЙ

1) Основанный на идеализме (1 зн.);выражающий принципы идеализма. И-ая философия. 2) Основанный на высоких идеалах (1 зн.); избегающий личной выгоды, наживы. И-ие порывы, намерения. И-ая натура.

**В первом значении это относительное прилагательное, а во втором - качественное.**

Качественные прилагательные обычно обозначают внутренние свойства предмета, при переходе относительных прилагательных в качественные они вступают в синонимичные отношения с другими качественными прилагательными, например: взгляды идеалистические, возвышенные, оторванные от реальной жизни.

Answer (score 1):

Это относительное прилагательное, т.к.  обозначает признак не прямо, а через его отношение к отвлеченному понятию ( идеалистические заблуждения)
Общее лексическое значение  может быть определено как «относящийся к идеалисту», «характерный для идеалиста». Это обстоятельство делает возможным замену  предложно-именным сочетанием идеалистическая философия=философия идеалиста. 
Суффикс -ическ- тоже говорит об относительности.

Правда,Зализняк даёт в парадигме краткие формы идеалистическ, идеалистическа, идеалистически, но для меня они звучат дико.Идеалистичны-другое слово.Вот степень сравнения,действительно, появилась.Воззрения могут стать ещё более идеалистическими,и  антоним есть, а вот наречий на -о, -е прилагательное не  образует.

И переносного смысла в связи с появлением краткой формы не появилось, как, например,братская могила, но братский союз. Видимо, это действительно относительное прилагательное с отдельными признаками качественного.Может, когда-то и перейдёт в качественное в каком-то значении, но пока не перешло.